# Сортировка выбором по 2 полям

Tags: c++, c, сортировка

В массиве несколько элементов структуры

```
  struct contact
 {
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};
```

Массив сортируется выбором по полю `nomer` (первые 2 цифры в поле могут повторяться у нескольких элементов) а среди элементов, у которых первые 2 цифры поля `nomer` одинаковы, происходит сортировка по полю `sname` по алфавиту. Пробовала считать количество элементов с совпадением и запускать по ним сортировку уже по полю `sname`. Как можно реализовать такую сортировку выьором без ошибок?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<string.h>

using namespace std;

struct contact
{
    char nomer[50];
    char adress[50];
    char sname[50];
};

int base_output(contact *buf, int kol_el)
{
    cout << "Полный список контактов базы данных\n";
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_el; i++)
    {
        cout << (i + 1) << ".) " << buf[i].sname;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].nomer;
        cout << "\n" << buf[i].adress;
        cout << "\n\n";
    }
    cout << "-----------------------------------------------------------\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void SelectSort(contact *buf, int kol_el)
{
    int count = 0;
    char check_num[3] = "00";
    for (int i = 0; i < kol_el - 1; i++)
    {
        int i_min = i;
        for (int j = i + 1; j < kol_el; j++)
        {
            if ((strcmp(buf[i_min].nomer, buf[j].nomer) > 0))
                i_min = j;
        }
        if (i_min != i)
        {
            swap(buf[i], buf[i_min]);
        }
        if ((strncmp(buf[i_min].nomer, check_num, 2)) == 0)
            count++;
        else
        {
            for (int k = i - count; k < i - 1; k++)
            {
                int k_min = k;
                for (int l = (i - count + 1); l < i; k++)
                {
                    if (strcmp(buf[l].sname, buf[k_min].sname) > 0)
                        k_min = l;
                }
                if (k_min != k)
                    swap(buf[k], buf[k_min]);
            }
            count = 1;
            strncpy(check_num, buf[i].nomer, 2);
        }
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RUS");
    FILE *f;
    f = fopen("telbook.dat", "r+b");
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(f);
    int kol_el = size / sizeof(contact);
    contact *buf = new contact[kol_el];
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_SET);
    fread(buf, sizeof(contact), kol_el, f);
    fclose(f);
    int first = 0;
    int last = kol_el;
    unsigned int rezh = 0;
    do{
        system("cls");
        const int NotUsed = system("color 03");
        cout << "1.Показать базу контактов.\n";
        cout << "2.Сортировка выбором\n";
        cout << "3.Выйти из программы.\n";
        cin >> rezh;
        switch (rezh)
        {    

        case 1:
        {
            base_output(buf, kol_el);
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            SelectSort(buf, kol_el);
            break;
        }

        }
    } while (rezh != 3);

    system("cls");
    system("pause");
    return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто воспользуйтесь одной составной функцией сравнения, и сортируйте, как обычно.

Что-то вроде

```
int contact_compare(const contact& c1, const contact& c2)
{
    int cmp = strncmp(c1.nomer,c2.nomer,2);
    if (cmp != 0) return cmp;
    return strcmp(c1.sname,c2.sname);
}
```

Можно даже написать свои операторы `>`, `<`, `==` для типа `contact` :) А дальше - просто обычная сортировка с единственным сравнением при помощи указанной функции.